# What is the recommended way to make uploaded content using file_selector available to main.py?

Tags: python, taipy

I am experimenting with file_selector to upload a yaml file and want to make the uploaded content available to my main.py program and view the content on my webpage. Currently I defined a global variable that holds the read content like below:

```
from taipy.gui import Gui
import yaml

parsed_data = dict()

path = None

md = "<|{path}|file_selector|label=Upload file|on_action=load_yaml_file|extensions=.yaml|>"

def load_yaml_file(state):
    global parsed_data

    with open(state.path, 'r') as file:
        yaml_data = file.read()

    # Parse the YAML data into a dictionary
    parsed_data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_data)

# other stuff

Gui(md).run()
```

What are other options instead of using a global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the state to display your variables.

Check out this [section of the documentation](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/getting_started/getting-started-gui/step_03/ReadMe/#multi-user-state) to understand the state.

> The state holds the value of all the variables used in the user
> interface for one specific connection.

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui
import yaml

parsed_data = dict()
parsed_data_str = ""

path = None

md = """
<|{path}|file_selector|label=Upload file|on_action=load_yaml_file|extensions=.yaml|>

<|{parsed_data_str}|input|active=False|multiline|>
"""

def load_yaml_file(state):
        with open(state.path, 'r') as file:
            yaml_data = file.read()

        # Parse the YAML data into a dictionary
        state.parsed_data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_data)
        state.parsed_data_str = yaml_data # you will see your yaml file as a string

# other stuff

Gui(md).run()
```

Now, you can retrieve `state.parsed_data` with what you have put inside. The *state* is always a parameter of callbacks in Taipy.

I also tried to include the answer on the page.